# Content from textbox sent to Email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey, so I'm working on a little email form, this is what I have so far:

```
Name:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" class="txt" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfname" />
            <br />
            <br />
            E-mail:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" class="txt" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+@\w+\.\w+" ControlToValidate="txtemail" />
            <br />
            <br />
            Message:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtmsg" runat="server" class="txt1" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300"
                Height="100" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmsg" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Send2Mail" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
```

I now need my last textbox content to be sent to my email:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtmsg" runat="server" class="txt1" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300"
```

I've been looking around and there seems to be some confusion with the Mail property, with different versions of VB.NET not working...

I'm working on version 3.5, and I've tried something like this on my code behind:

```
Dim objMail As New System.Net.Mail()

        objMail.To = "TAREGET_EMAIL@ADRESS"
        objMail.From = txtemail.Text
        objMail.Subject = "Contact form - Joao"
        objMail.Body = "Name : " + txtname.Text + vbNewLine + "Email : " + txtemail.text + vbNewLine + "Message : " + txtmsg.text
```

This is not working though, and the biggest issue seems to be from declaring this Mail variable...

Any tips on how to get my the content from txtmsg to my email?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Const ToAddress As String =  "you@youremail.com"
Dim mm As New MailMessage(txtemail.Text, ToAddress)


    mm.Subject =  "Contact form - Joao"
    mm.Body ="Name : " + txtname.Text + vbNewLine + "Email : " + txtemail.text + vbNewLine + "Message : " + txtmsg.text

    mm.IsBodyHtml = False

   Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

   smtp.Send(mm)
```

have a look on this https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx

hope it may help you

Comment: yes. If you are in higher version. No need to worry about lower version

Comment: well, from what i understood, i simply needed to follow the instructions below "Sending an Administrator Email Through a Feedback Web Page", i've added the code to my buttons click event and i'm getting a lot of errors: MailMessage is outdated, mm.IsBodyHtml is not a member of MailMessage... smtpclient is not defined, etc etc..

Comment: you are added the namespace properly?

Comment: thanks, seems like it needed to be "Imports System.Net.Mail", not Imports "System.Web.Mail" ;), but i need help with something else now, do I need to provide the SMTP Servers Details? and if so, is this my own email server setting or?...